# Spring 5 correct configuration in WildFly Server 20

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, wildfly

I'm workin in a new simple project with **Spring 5** and **WildFly 20**, I configured programmatically (*via annotations*) the implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` interface and a `WebConfig` class, and when I run the project it shows: **404 - Not Found** in my web browser. Anyone can help me please?, What am I doing wrong?. This is my code:

`WebApplicationInitializer` :

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sctx) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext contexto = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        contexto.register(WebConfig.class);
        contexto.setServletContext(sctx);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = sctx.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", new 
        DispatcherServlet(contexto));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");
    }
}
```

`WebConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.config" })
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I changed the `servlet.addMapping("/*");` from **"/"** to **"/*"** but it still doesn't working. My **JSP** is just a simple `index.jsp` with "Helo world".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I realized that **WildFly doesn't work like Tomcat** (*I know it's something obvious*), in Eclipse Tomcat assign the project name to the Context Application, something like: `localhost:8080/<project-name>` while WildFly assign the `<artifactId>` and `<version>`from `pom.xml` file, something like: `localhost:8080/<artifactId><version>`.

I couldn't see that because when a ran the project by **right click on project** > **Run As** > **Run on Server**, automatically Eclipse opens an embebed web explorer like `localhost:8080/<project-name>`.

The solution was add the tag `<warName>springapp</warName>` in my `pom.xml` file and that's all. I know that is something easy but I had not noticed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-boot, check jasper and jstl in the list of dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And using this view class to enable explicit JSTL support.

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}
```

https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: No, I'm using Spring 5 and WildFly not Spring Boot.

Comment: Check contextPath, run on server your project.

Comment: I think you've missed a very small one. Watch the tutorial and set it again slowly. :)

Comment: Thanks @0gam but it still not working, I found a solution, probably I'II post it. :)